# Extract a substring using XPath where there might be no trailing delimiter in the field

Tags: vb.net, xpath

I'm trying to parse an XML file where the users (in their infinite wisdom) type a key value into a free-form field, `<Description>`. The values are normally typed in with returns (BR's?) between them. For instance:

```
<Description>
% Increase: 27%
Completion Date: 10-Aug-2015
</Description>
```

I need to look for an extract the date following the string "Completion Date:" Looking around here on SO I found something similar and adapted it to:

```
compdate = deal.SelectSingleNode("./Terms/Description[substring-before(substring-after(.,'Completion Date:'),'/')]")
```

The problem is that in the original question there was a trailing character that could be used to delimit the text, a /. In my case, there might be a BR of some sort, or it might be the last (as in this case) or only item on the line and thus there's no delimiter.

So... suggestions on how to extract the date? I can do it on the VB side, but I'd like to remain in the XPath world for code clarity - unless of course the resulting XPath is unreadable.

Comment: So there might be other substrings after `10-Aug-2015`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  XPath 2.0 solution is acceptable, try

```
./Terms/Description/tokenize(substring-after(.,'Completion Date: '), '\n')[1]
```

If not and date format is always `DD-mon-YYYY` (e.g. `01-Dec-2018`), try

```
./Terms/Description/substring(substring-after(.,'Completion Date: '), 1, 11)
```

Comment: Oh, I like the first one much better, it is more in keeping with how I would solve the same problem in VB, which is a plus.

Comment: Except I find that MS does not support 2.0.... of course, it's only what, 15 years old?